# How to fill in the blanks in 两个队的分数_都很_近?

Tags: grammar, characters, sentence-structure

> 两个队的分数_都很_近.

The spaces are where words/phrases are supposed to go.

Are there such words that fit in these spaces? I've been going through Google trying to find similar sentence structures but to no avail.

Comment: 填空符号／＂fill in blanks＂ symbol ：＿＿＿＿＿＿ long underline／长下划线

Comment: instead of googling why not use 小马词典，＂Show all compounds containing 都、近＂？ 为什么使用Google搜索该句话而不查小马词典，＂显示所有包含“都、近＂的复合词＂呢？

Answer (score 2):

两个队的分数**全**都很**接**近

shall work. however, this will imply that each team has multiple scores (like score for goals, for shots, for passes, etc.) and all scores are close.

Comment: other possibilities beside 全都、接近：大都 for the most part ； mostly，相近 close ； near ； be similar to ； be close to

Answer (score 1):

两个队的分数都很**接**近 already makes sense to me, and doesn't specify whether each team has multiple scores or not. However, it seems that you need another word or phrase between 都 and 很.

If they do have multiple scores, the example that @siyi gave would work.

If not, you could try 两个队的分数**其实**都很**接**近, where 其实 means "actually".

Comment: Because of "都", even 两个队的分数都很接近 sounds like the speaker is comparing multiple scores of the two teams. Anyway, the design of the question is poor.